# Bootstrap Navbar will expand but not collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code for producing a responsive navbar that collapses:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="navbar-brand">HOME</div>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" id="navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When clicking the icon-bar the menu will expand, but will not collapse when I click it again.

Comment: The code snippet is working fine on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e0d8my79/116/ Try checking your browser console. Might be a javascript conflict or something

Comment: Nothing in the console. I'm now thinking it may be something to do with my local host (which I set up using the command http-server -p 3000)

Comment: I changed my bootstrap links to the cdn's you uploaded onto jsfiddle and it now works. There must be something wrong in my local bootstrap files. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad I could help Ryan. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

Same behavior happens if you include bootstrap script 2 times (I'm using webpack)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there was a problem with my local bootstrap files, and when I used a cdn instead there were no issues.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a import 'bootstrap' in my app.component.ts which I had to remove and its working now.